# Why returned value is always 1.797693134862316e+308

Tags: mql4, mql5

i try to include a indicator in my ea, but i still get as results always "1.797693134862316e+308" if i print out the copied datas from the icustom-function.

```
int iCustomHandle;
double trendline_buy_signal[];
double trendline_sell_signal[];
double trendline_sl_price[];
double trendline_tp1_price[];
double trendline_tp2_price[];
double trendline_tp3_price[];

int OnInit()
{    
   iCustomHandle = iCustom(symbol, time, "\\Indicators\\Market\\myindicator.ex5");      
   if(iCustomHandle == INVALID_HANDLE){ return(INIT_FAILED);   }    
   return (INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

void OnTick()
{   
int valueDistance = 0; 

    int calculatedInd = BarsCalculated(iCustomHandle);
    
    ArraySetAsSeries(trendline_buy_signal, true);
    ArraySetAsSeries(trendline_sell_signal, true);
    ArraySetAsSeries(trendline_sl_price, true);     
    ArraySetAsSeries(trendline_tp1_price, true);   
    ArraySetAsSeries(trendline_tp2_price, true);   
    ArraySetAsSeries(trendline_tp3_price, true);   
    int copied;    
    
     copied = CopyBuffer(iCustomHandle, 2, 0, calculatedInd, trendline_buy_signal); 
     copied = CopyBuffer(iCustomHandle, 8, 0, calculatedInd, trendline_sell_signal);
     copied = CopyBuffer(iCustomHandle, 9, 0, calculatedInd, trendline_sl_price);
     copied = CopyBuffer(iCustomHandle, 10, 0, calculatedInd, trendline_tp1_price);
     copied = CopyBuffer(iCustomHandle, 11, 0, calculatedInd, trendline_tp2_price);
     copied = CopyBuffer(iCustomHandle, 12, 0, calculatedInd, trendline_tp3_price);    
    
    
    Print("calculatedInd:",calculatedInd," > iCustom bufferr: buy_signal:", trendline_buy_signal[valueDistance],
            " > sell_signal:",trendline_sell_signal[valueDistance],
            " > sl_price:",trendline_sl_price[valueDistance],
            " > tp1:",trendline_tp1_price[valueDistance],
            " > tp2:",trendline_tp2_price[valueDistance],
            " > tp3:",trendline_tp3_price[valueDistance]);
}
```

What is the reason for it and how i can solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That looks like the maximum value of a "double" floating point data type, which could be used to represent positive infinity, which could arise from dividing by zero. Is there anywhere in the code where a division by zero could have happened?

Comment: my problem is that i dont know what kind of result from the icustoms() function comes, also i dont know wich additonal parameter it needs. For the moment i have no idear, and the code above is complete for that points.

Answer (score 0):

you get EMPTY_VALUE so You should use something like this:
if(Value != EMPTY_VALUE)
Print(Value);

Comment: The returned value is not an EMPTY_VALUE. Empty value is defined as 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF)